# Find the closest multiple, of a number m, to another number n

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Let there be a number $n$. Let there also be a number $m$. Then is there a way of finding the closest multiple of $m$ to number $n$, where that multiple is more than or equal to $n$?

I admit the wording is a bit weird, but here's an example. If $n=5$ and $m=3$, then the closest multiple of $3$ to $5$ is $6$. Basically, I need to find the multiple of $m$ that is closest to $n$. At the moment this is the function I came up with: $$f(n)=\left\lceil \frac nm \right\rceil \times m$$ where $f(n)$ is a function that returns the closest multiple. Obviously: $$n\leq f(n)$$
This is not for a math problem or anything, just something I was working on because I like to mess with numbers in my free time. So I have no idea if a function for this exact question already exists or not. Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Note that if $n/m$ is a perfect integer the ceiling function becomes an identity, so the whole returns the correct answer of $n$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Oh, so I'm good to go with this? If yes, may I ask is there a better way of writing: $f(n)-n=\lceil \frac nm \rceil \times m - n$? Actually, let me edit the question, so it's better to see :)

Comment: Don't expect things to become simpler when you have the most obvious form of something.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Actually, when editing the question, I thought about it and yeah, I think I'm overcomplicating it. I should just stick with the simple form I found. I just wanted confirmation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is correct.

Clearly $f(n)$ is a multiple of $m$.

Also, $$ \lceil \frac{n}{m}\rceil - 1< \frac{n}{m} \le \lceil \frac{n}{m}\rceil $$

Multiply by $m$, we have

$$f(n) - m < n \le f(n) $$

$f(n)-m$ is the largest multiple of $m$ smaller than $n$. Hence $f(n)$ is the quantity that we are looking for.

Remark if $m$ is negative, just take the absolute value and work with $|m|$. If $m$ is $0$, then the solution is $0$.